# jquery autocomplete serviceURL changing

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

My function for autocomplete is:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var a = $('#issued_to').autocomplete(
  {
    serviceUrl: 'http://myhost.com/ecard_emp_suggestion/',
    minChars: 1,
    delimiter: /(,|;)\s*/, // regex or character
    maxHeight: 400,
    width: 300,
    zIndex: 9999,
    deferRequestBy: 0, //miliseconds
    //params: { country:'Yes' }, //aditional parameters
    noCache: false, //default is false, set to true to disable caching
    // callback function:
    onSelect: function(value, data){ alert('You selected: ' + value + ', ' + data); },
    // local autosugest options:
    //lookup: ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May'] //local lookup values
  });
});
```

Now the problem is, it sends request to:
http://myhost.com/ecard_emp_suggestion?query=input_text

but i need http://myhost.com/ecard_emp_suggestion/input_text

what & where should I change??

Answer (score 1):

In short, you shouldn't do it, mainly because of escaping issues. Most backends will not work with a random string in URL segments like `http://myhost/com/card_emp_suggestion/space included`.
You should look at the [jquery ui project's autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#option-source) that allows a callback for source and you can implement your backend calling in whatever way you want.

Answer (score 0):

You will have to override the function getSuggestions with a custom one, so after you initialize the autocomplete in the ready function add the following code:

```
a.getSuggestions = function(q) {
  var cr, me;
  cr = this.isLocal ? this.getSuggestionsLocal(q) : this.cachedResponse[q];
  if (cr && $.isArray(cr.suggestions)) {
    this.suggestions = cr.suggestions;
    this.data = cr.data;
    this.suggest();
  } else if (!this.isBadQuery(q)) {
    me = this;
    //me.options.params.query = q;
    //$.get(this.serviceUrl, me.options.params, function(txt) { me.processResponse(txt); }, 'text');
    $.get(this.serviceUrl + '/' + q, null, function(txt) { me.processResponse(txt); }, 'text');
  }
}
```

Comment: I would add a encodeUriComponent() around the q variable in the last line like this:
$.get(this.serviceUrl + '/' +  encodeUriComponent(q), // .. rest of the line